# if ca ≡ cb mod n and d = (c,n) where n = dm . prove that a ≡ b mod m

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

if $ca \equiv cb \ (\textrm{mod}\ n)$ and d = (c,n) where n = dm , prove that 
$a \equiv b \ (\textrm{mod}\ m)$

so here is my attempt

from 
$ca \equiv cb \ (\textrm{mod}\ n)$ we know that n | ca - cb and so n | c(a-b) 
and there exists an integer k such that nk = c(a-b)

also since d = (c,n) then we know there exists integers x and y such that 
d = cx + ny  and since n = dm then we can conclude that since nk = c(a-b) then 
m(dk) = c(a-b) and so $ca \equiv cb \ (\textrm{mod}\ m)$ nut i need to find a way to conclude that m | a - b   , i think i have to get that (m,c) = 1 then i can conlcude it but how to get (m,c) = 1?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you have done already, here is one possible proof: write $c=dk$.  Then $k$ and $m$ are coprime and
$$\eqalign{
  ca\equiv cb\pmod n\quad
  &\Rightarrow\quad n\mid ca-cb\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad dm\mid dk(a-b)\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad m\mid k(a-b)\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad m\mid a-b\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad a\equiv b\pmod m\ .}$$
The second last step is true because $k$ and $m$ are coprime.